# Filter dataset in repository design pattern C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, repository-pattern

I have a given below query, which is perfect

```
SELECT
    MAX(WarehouseId)       AS WareHouseId, 
    MAX(CompanyId)         AS CompanyId, 
    MAX(ProductId)         AS ProductId,
    SUM(AvailableQuantity) AS AvailableQuantity,
    PurchaseItemPrice 
FROM
    PurchaseItem 
WHERE
    CompanyId = 1 
GROUP BY
    PurchaseItemPrice
ORDER BY
    MAX(ProductId) ASC
```

Which I needs to convert into given below format instead of linq. I really don't know what is the name of given below format. Please also tell me what we can call this format and if this is not a good approach to get data please suggest something better because I'm new to repository design pattern.

```
unitOfWork.PurchaseItemRepository.DataSet
    .Where( x => x.CompanyId == id )
    .ToList()
    .GroupBy( x => x.PurchaseItemPrice )
    .Select( x =>
        x.Max( y => new
        {
            y.WarehouseId,
            y.CompanyId,
            y.ProductId,
            y.AvailableQuantity
        } )
    );

public IRepository<PurchaseItem> PurchaseItemRepository
{
    get
    {
        if (_PurchaseItemRepository == null)
        {
            dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            _PurchaseItemRepository = new Repository<PurchaseItem>(dbContext);
        }
        return _PurchaseItemRepository;
    }
}
```

And **ProductItem is an Entity**

Moreover, when I executed above code, It will display given below error.

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional information: At least one object must implement IComparable.

Comment: Can you show the code for `PurchaseItemRepository`?

Comment: @OJRaqueño thanks for responding. Please check the updated code.

Comment: Note it makes no sense to use `Max` with an anonymous object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a way to determine the max.   What are you doing max on how is the compiler going to know what property you want to use max on?

you probably want to grab the MAX on each one of those properties individually.
  I.e

```
 unitOfWork.PurchaseItemRepository.DataSet
      .Where(x => x.CompanyId == id).ToList()
      .GroupBy(x => x.PurchaseItemPrice)
      .Select(x => new {
        WarehouseId = x.OrderByDescending(v => v.WarehouseId).FirstOrDefault(),
        CompanyId = x.OrderByDescending(v => v.CompanyId).FirstOrDefault(),
        //Do the rest here 
      }).OrderBy( output => output.ProductId )
      .ToList();
```

As a side note you probably shouldn't be calling `ToList()` this will materialize the whole table.  You should work with `IQuerables` instead so you can filter without pulling the whole table

Comment: So, It's mean, working with IQuerables is a better approach ? If yes, then please share an example, so I can implement it.

Comment: @Ibtisam as @Dai points out the repository pattern is more of an anti pattern in general.  If your just using it to store common queries that's one thing.  If you want to use IQueryables, its as simple as removing `ToList` and changing the return type to be IQueryable instead of IEnumerable.    If this satisfies your original question please upvote and Mark as Correct.

Answer (score -2):

(BTW, you do not need to use the Repository (anti-)pattern with Linq and Entity Framework because the `DbContext` *is* the repository. Note that creating classes to hold predefined Linq queries is not the same thing as a Repository. I'm also not convinced that the Unit-of-Work Pattern is of much use with Entity Framework either as a short-lived `DbContext` in a `using` block with a Transaction also fulfils that role)

```
var list = dbContext.PurchaseItems
    .Where( x => x.CompanyId == 1 )
    .GroupBy( x => x.PurchaseItemPrice )
    .Select( grp => new {
        PurchaseItemPrice = grp.Key,
        WarehouseId       = grp.Max( x => x.WarehouseId ),
        CompanyId         = grp.Max( x => x.CompanyId ),
        ProductId         = grp.Max( x => x.ProductId ),
        AvailableQuantity = grp.Sum( x => x.AvailableQuantity ),
    } )
    .OrderBy( output => output.ProductId )
    .ToList();
```

`list` will need to use inferred type (`var`) because of the use of an anonymous-type in the `.Select` call. If you change it to a custom record-type then you can use `List<MyOutputRecordType>` instead.

Comment: I highly disagree. Repository pattern is not anti pattern. It decouples data access layer from the application. Since I have to move some older apps, which run directly with DbContext on .NET Framework to EF Core. Let me tell you. I wish the guy before me used Repository pattern.